# Tell Safari to Download Certain File Types?

Tags: safari, data-transfer

There are certain file types that Safari automatically opens natively.  Various kinds of video files, for example.  Is there a way to configure Safari to not open these files and instead default to just downloading them?

I'm using Safari 5.1 on OS X 10.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about *permanently*, but you can hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key when clicking on a link, and that will always download it instead of opening it.  Similarly, if you put a URL into the address bar and type <kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>return</kbd>, that will download it as well.

Comment: Not permanent, but it'll do.  Thanks!

Comment: Just to add, right clicking a link will provide a context menu that will also allow you to "Download as..." instead of allowing Safari to load the contents. It also of note that Safari takes it's cues from server, so if the website says "view this file" then Safari will load it in the window. Even zip files can be loaded (show ulnas gibberish). There are entries one can execute using apache, for example, that tell browsers to either download or preview specific content. But browsers kind of do what they are told when rendering web content.