# How make Safari always download CSV files instead of opening them in-page?

Tags: safari, csv

When you click on a link containing to a CSV file, Safari renders it by default.  Most other browsers will download them in this circumstance and I'd like to make Safari do the same.

What's the setting to make that happen?

Comment: Related [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/24012/121968).

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't always work.  For example, If the site has a download button that has an action on it to generate the file rather than just being a link to the file.  Also, specifically, with CSVs, they download as a .csv.webarchive file and even after renaming them to just csv, they're a bit mangled and not a pure csv.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Unfortunately, your question doesn't provide enough detail for us to help you. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer. For now, can you please edit your question (there's an edit link below it) to add info such as: (1) Is this Safari on a Mac or another device? (2) Regardless of the device, what version is the OS you're running? (3) What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: Answered more directly here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332907/fine-tuning-open-safe-files-after-downloading

Answer (score 4):

Let Safari open the CSV, then press <kbd>Command</kbd>/<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and have done some web searching and have not found a good answer.  This does work consistently for me in Chrome so when I need to export a CSV, I just do it in Chrome.  I have been able to cut/paste the Safari text into TextEdit, switch it to "text only" formatting and then save the file as a CSV, but this is so clicky -- if I'm going to do it more than once or twice, I just switch to Chrome for that browser session.