# Fine-tuning "Open safe files after downloading"

Tags: safari, file, daemons

Is it possible to fine-tune the "Open safe files after downloading" setting in Safari? For example, to make Safari open files like ".ical" et. al., but *not* Zip-files.

If macOS has no built-in support for this, could a solution be a UNIX script daemon that instantly detects new files in the Downloads directory and opens files with certain extensions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The preferences file is located at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.DownloadAssessment.plist`

If the file doesn't exist, then create it and include the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com-PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> 
<plist version="1.0"> 
    <dict> 
        <key>LSRiskCategorySafe</key> 
        <dict> 
            <key>LSRiskCategoryExtensions</key> 
            <array> 
                <string>docx</string> 
                <string>xlsx</string> 
            </array> 
        </dict> 
    </dict> 
</plist>
```

To exclude Zip files, add the following to the preferences:

```
<dict> 
    <key>LSRiskCategoryNeutral</key> 
    <dict> 
        <key>LSRiskCategoryExtensions</key> 
        <array> 
            <string>zip</string> 
        </array> 
    </dict> 
</dict>
```

More info at: [Source](https://www.blackmanticore.com/1c569206754935dacb0dc6b89ca818b8)

Comment: You can also hold the alt button `⌥` when clicking a link on a per-download basis

Comment: So they thought of it. That's beautiful! Thanks for a quick and precise answer!

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help!

Comment: I used this successfully but it does not work on Catalina anymore. Has anybody found how to do this now?

Comment: @C.Ramseyer I was able to get it working by adding Safari to Catalina's new security restrictions at: >System Preferences>Security&Privacy>Privacy> Full Disk Access