# Fine-tuning “Open safe files after downloading” - Catalina Edition

Tags: safari

How can I change what Safari considers a "Safe File" that opens directly when downloaded? [Pre-Catalina used to have `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.DownloadAssessment.plist`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332907/fine-tuning-open-safe-files-after-downloading), and this worked perfectly but unfortunately not anymore.

Anybody knows how to do that now?

Comment: When I migrated from Mojave, Safari stopped opening PDF files in preview.  It just downloads them, in spite of checking the relevant box.  So it would be great to know a solution to this.