# Change Safari Safe File Types for Big Sur

Tags: safari

I know there is a similar answer here:

[Fine-tuning "Open safe files after downloading"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332907/fine-tuning-open-safe-files-after-downloading)

But, the answer seems to not work in Big Sur because I can no longer find the file:

coms.apple.downloadassessment.plist

Can anyone tell me how to add a file type to the safe list for opening immediately after download in Safari for Big Sur?

Specifically, I would like to automatically launch Citrix .ica files immediately after download.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an automator action that will do what you want. I'm a Mac Citrix user as well, and it works for me:

[image: Automator Action which automatically opens ICA files downloaded from Safari]

Answer (score 1):

I'm proposing an alternative here, going forward, since the option isn't there anymore, why not use Automator and/or Shortcuts for Mac (starting from Monterey).

You could check the "Downloads" folder for any new .ica files and open them immediately.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with automator. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure, Automator is an integrated Mac app that allows for various automation to take place. 
<br/>
Your automation could be:
> Watch the download folder
> If any new .ica files appears
>> Open it with Citrix 
<br/>
Two videos that could help you get started :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYcBTlN9_vM
&
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LaitUcUEqg